# OpsHub VSTS Migration OH-TFS-Connector-0051 Value Area

Tags: migration, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, opshub

I am migrating workitems from TFS 2015 Update 3 to VSTS and running into an error::InvalidEmpty for field [Value Area] value []". Queries on the source display "Business" as the value for all Workitems. Any help is appreciated.

```
2018-02-21 10:23:02,875 [4] ERROR    at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWorkItemClient.createOrUpdateWIEntity(TFSWorkItem workItemInfo, Boolean serviceValidation, Boolean isUserImpersonation, WorkItem workItem) in g:\work\git_workspace\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWorkItemClient.cs:line 639
2018-02-21 10:23:02,875 [4] ERROR Error : Failed to create/update entity because : 
    InvalidEmpty for field [Value Area] value []

   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWorkItemClient.createOrUpdateWIEntity(TFSWorkItem workItemInfo, Boolean serviceValidation, Boolean isUserImpersonation, WorkItem workItem) in g:\work\git_workspace\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWorkItemClient.cs:line 649
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWorkItemClient.createOrUpdateWIEntity(TFSWorkItem workItemInfo, Boolean serviceValidation, Boolean isUserImpersonation) in g:\work\git_workspace\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWorkItemClient.cs:line 487
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.createOrUpdateEntity(String authToken, TFSWorkItem workItem, Boolean serviceValidation, Boolean isUserImpersonation) in g:\work\git_workspace\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 35
   at SyncInvokecreateOrUpdateEntity(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: How do you query on the source? Do you mean create a query with Value Area filter?

Comment: Yes, a query shows the value as being set. What may be causing the issue that Rev 1 of the workitem does not have a Value Area by itself. Later revisions of the workitem have it. So when it is trying to create one/migrate in VSTS, VSTS is making sure that the value is present in revision 1 hence failing and blocking way for the revision that has the vale area set.

Comment: How many workitems have this issue?

Comment: all of them since they were all created based on the source version.